# How to convert column (category type) into columns without losing columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a data frame with many columns. I want to turn the values in the category type column ('Series Name)' into columns without losing the other columns. 
Below you can see what I did:

I have this 
[image]

and I use this code:

```py
education_level.pivot(index=education_level.index, columns='Series Name')['Value']
```

And the result is this: [image]

So I lose the columns 'Country Name', 'Country Code', and 'Year'. And I don't want that. I hope somebody can help me with this issue.

I want to get the following final result:
Country name - Country Code - Year - Category 1 - Category 2 - ...
Meaning, I want to get the data for a country for a single year on one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all colmbinations of values in `cols` list are unique, use `set_index` with `unstack`:

```
cols = ['Country name','Country Code','Year','Series Name']
df = education_level.set_index(cols)['Value'].unstack()
```

If not, use `pivot_table` with aggregate function - e.g. `mean`:

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['Country name','Country Code','Year'],
                     columns='Series Name',
                     values='Value',
                     aggfunc='mean')
```

Comment: I get this mistake: 
```python
KeyError: 'None of [RangeIndex(start=0, stop=11284, step=1)] are in the [columns]'
```

Comment: @Yana if use `df = education_level.pivot(index=education_level.index, columns='Series Name')['Value']` it working?

Comment: Um Actually. It didn't work.
I use 
```python
df = education_level.pivot(index=education_level.index, columns='Series Name')['Value']
education_level = education_level.drop(["Series Name", "Value"], axis = 1)
education_level = education_level.join(df)
```
But it deletes the years

Comment: @Yana - Can you explain more?

Comment: @Yana - are you sure? Maybe not displayed only, check `education_level = education_level.join(df)` and `print (education_level.columns)`

Comment: So, I use the code as you wrote it:
```python
df = education_level.pivot(index=education_level.index, columns='Series Name')['Value']
education_level = education_level.join(df)
print(education_level.columns)
```
I get this columns:
Index(['Country Name', 'Country Code', 'Series Name', 'Year', 'Value',.so on. 
But I don't need Series Name and Value anymore. And I dont get the result for one country and one year on the same row.

Comment: @Yana - I think now understand, please check edited answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196854/discussion-between-yana-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

First, a pivot_table has to be made:

```py
education_level= education_level.pivot_table(index=['Country Name','Country Code','Year'],
                     columns='Series Name',
                     values='Value',
                     aggfunc='mean')
```

Then, since I don't want multi indexing, I create categories and then reset the indexes:

```py
education_level.columns = education_level.columns.add_categories(['Country Name','Country Code','Year'])
education_level.columns = pd.Index(list(education_level.columns))
education_level.reset_index(level=education_level.index.names, inplace = True)
```